# Are Mac users stuck with App Store options only for package installers? If so, can you install DNF or YUM on a Mac manually?

Tags: macbook, package-management

I run the latest OS.  I am trying to learn DNF and would rather not pay to get virtual machine software to do it.

Comment: Thanks.  I was initially trying to install the info command on Mac.  but maybe it does not have one.

Comment: You mean like GNU Texinfo? brew has it.

Comment: `dnf` and `yum` are strictly RedHat/CentOS. For macOS, the equivalent is [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: Yes, the information pages.  Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is the most popular open source package manager on macOS. Over the years there were others, such as MacPorts and Fink. Some of them have taken inspiration from Linux and BSD package managers.

Installing a Linux package manager on macOS  isn't terribly useful for most people, because without a community of people creating and publishing packages for macOS for that system, you don't end up with a big enough library of packages compared to a popular package manager like Homebrew, so everyone seems to stick with Homebrew.

Comment: “Installing a Linux package manager on macOS isn't terribly useful for most people…” Can that even be done? How would that work? Install Homebrew and then run `brew install dnf` or `brew install yum`? That would be wretched to deal with.